# K-Means output the similar to each other cluster

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, k-means

I am trying to run K-Means on my data set of house price prediction problem.

After running it, the output of the model seems wrong because the graphs look the same as each other.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

n_clusters = 4
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=0, verbose=0, n_jobs=int(0.8*n_cores)).fit(X_train)
c_train = kmeans.predict(X_train)
c_pred = kmeans.predict(X_val)
```

You guys can try with my [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t3Ygi4Z4hJyM8i8WOTJ8ZR3cF0CFFkn-?usp=sharing). Just create a copy of my notebook and then you can run my code.

The data set is cleaned and only contains numerical values.

Below is the example of the graph.

Do you guys know what is wrong about this? Thanks.

**Update:**

This is how I visualize the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_clusters = 8

color = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w']
for i in range(0, n_clusters):
  plt.scatter(
      X_train[c_train == i, 0], X_train[c_train == i, 1],
      s=50, c=color[i],
      marker='s', edgecolor='black',
      label='cluster '+str(i)
  )
  plt.legend(scatterpoints=1)
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()

plt.scatter(
      kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1],
      s=250,
      c='red', edgecolor='black',
      label='centroids'
)
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

Thanks to @StupidWolf answer, I can see the pattern of my dataset.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
PCs = pca.fit_transform(X_scaled)

n_clusters = 4
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(X_scaled)
c_train = kmeans.predict(X_scaled)

sns.scatterplot(x=PCs[:, 0], y=PCs[:, 1], hue=c_train)
```

[image]

Comment: how did you obtain the plots above?

Comment: @StupidWolf Sorry for the late response. I just add the plot visualize code. Is it correct to plot like that, because my dataset is multidimensional so we cannot plot a graph that has a dimension greater than 3?

Comment: how many columns does your data frame contain? And can you provide the source of your data. I suspect the first two columns are too low and not actually used in the clustering

Comment: @StupidWolf The original data has 106 columns but after I did some preprocessing steps, it has 160 columns. The source of the data I use is the [London](http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html) dataset. I think it has many features so I cannot visualize it in 2d-dimensional.

Comment: ok there are so many files under london and i can't tell which one is it. You can do a pca on your 160 columns and plot the first 2 pcs. Then you will see the difference.

Comment: @StupidWolf I use the `listings.csv` dataset. On the Colab link I mentioned above, there is the code I import the data after I had done the preprocessing step or you can get my data from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhuy237/Booking-System-Price-Prediction/huy/data/data_cleaned_2.csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not provide the data, most likely the variables you are plotting are columns from the dataset that are not useful in the clustering or are too small in magnitude. I will use an example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

np.random.seed(111)
iris = datasets.load_iris()

df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns=iris.feature_names)
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':np.random.uniform(0,1,150),'x2':np.random.uniform(0,1,150)})
df = pd.concat([d1,df],axis=1)
```

The first two columns don't have useful information and are lower in magnitude compared to the iris data. So if you run kmeans and only plot the first two columns, you see no pattern:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns

X_train = df.sample(100)
X_val = df.drop(X_train.index).to_numpy()

X_train = X_train.to_numpy()

n_clusters = 4
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(X_train)
c_train = kmeans.predict(X_train)
sns.scatterplot(x=X_train[:,0],y=X_train[:,1],hue=c_train)
```

[image]

The better way is to scale your data, do kmeans and plot on a PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
PCs = pca.fit_transform(X_scaled)

n_clusters = 3
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(X_scaled)
c_train = kmeans.predict(X_scaled)

sns.scatterplot(x=PCs[:,0],y=PCs[:,1],hue=c_train)
```

[image]

So you can do likewise for your data, scale all columns, perform kmeans and plot on PCA

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I will apply your instructions with my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

K-means is not the right tool to use if you are looking to predict the price of houses based on some datasets. K-means is rather a clustering method to be used to solve unsupervised classification problems.

Regression algorithms are the best tool that helps you make predictions of house prices by learning from existing statistical data.

You can use K-means here but in the prediction task. You can for example use it to cluster the houses you have in your datasets into a number of clusters based on their prices.

Comment: I just want cluster the dataset first, but the plot look not familiar to me, all the cluster look the same and I don't know what is the problem here.